# Background property to fit the whole screen without loosing data

Tags: html, css, background

I´m facing this issue: I have an illustrator background that has some details on the edges and I would like to make it a background picture. The problem is, when I try to set background-size, it either looses the detailing or it does not fit the whole screen.
Can you recommend what property should I use? 
Thanks a lot fot your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```css
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Please, have a look at the article linked below stating different other approaches to do so.

[Perfect Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: This does not work :( It looks as if there was a margin around the background leaving 1cm around it. Even though I set margin and padding to 0

Comment: Did you set `margin: 0;` on body element ?

Comment: * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body, html {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }

.start {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}